# Qgis OSM and layer projection problem

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I am using QGIS 2.1.0, and  trying to import my vector layer(parcels) with OpenStreetMap layer.
My vector layer (parcels) use EPSG 31277 coordinate system.

This is the definition for EPSG 31277:

```
(+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs)
```

OpenStreetMap layer use  WGS 84/Pseudo Mercator EPSG 3857.

My project use WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator EPSG 3857.
In project properties I enable 'on the flay' crs transformation.

The problem is that my parcels do not match with OpenStreetMap layer!
The difference is about 300 m. Here is a picture that shows that.

[image]

Comment: Please also keep in mind, that you fullfil the OSM licence requirements, if you mix different datasources: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some discussion about the right +towgs84 parameters for projections based on MGI Ferro, see
[Problem with reprojecting raster from MGI 6 to WGS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56773/problem-with-reprojecting-raster-from-mgi-6-to-wgs)

[Projection parameters for Gauss Kruger 7 zone Serbia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70515/projection-parameters-for-gauss-kruger-7-zone-serbia)

As a result, we now have two similar projections in QGIS 2.0.1:

```
EPSG:3909 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

EPSG:31277 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=21 +k=0.9999 +x_0=7500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs
```

Maybe your data fits better if you assign the EPSG:3909 projection to it with `Rightclick -> Set CRS for layer`.