# National grid and OpenLayers do not match

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have points in a txt file with lon, lat and elevation. The CRS is the National Grid of my country (metric system). However, when I add them in QGIS and then try to lay over them a map from OpenLayers plugin, the points are 50 meters off their true location. How to fix this?

The national grid is Balkan Zone 7.

Comment: Make sure the **Project** CRS is set to EPSG:3857 and the `on-the-fly reprojection` option is enabled.

Comment: Now it's even further away.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try removing the layer, set the project CRS (with `otf` enabled), add the OpenLayers plugin layer, then finally add the point layer. See if that helps. You could also consider using the **QuickMapServices** plugin which is better maintained and offers a lot more imagery layers =)

Comment: Thank you for the plugin suggestion, but still nothing. I have points which were transformed to Balkan Zone 7. I also set my project CRS to that grid and also the 'on-the-fly projection', but still no success. They are 50 meters off...

Comment: Just don't use OpenLayers plugin at all. QuickMapServices only.

Comment: What CRS have you chosen for Balkan Zone 7? We have EPSG:3909 and 31277. Both use different datum shifts. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200917/problem-with-mgi-crs-on-the-balkan leads to further reading on that.

Comment: AndreJ you nailed it! The problem was that I chose EPSG:31277 everytime. I switched to MGI 1901 and it works like charm!
Thanks.