# Converting coordinate systems of shapefiles using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have two *shapefiles* representing the same GPS track taken at different times.  However, they have different coordinate systems so they do not match, they are separated by about 354 meters E/W.  I would like to convert them to the same coordinate system so that they overlay each other.  Both were exported directly from Trimble Pathfinder Office.

Shape1 has the CRS `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs`

Shape2 has the CRS `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`

in QGIS I saved Shape2 to the CRS of Shape1, but it did not change its position.  I also saved Shape1 to the CRS of Shape2, and it also did not change its position.  In both cases the two *shapefiles* remained separate by about 354 meters.

Comment: What country is the data in? Germany?

Comment: Based on other question: If Croatia, layer may be using EPSG:3907 (MGI 1901 / Balkans zone 5), which would need a +towgs84 in its definition like +towgs84=551.7,162.9,467.9,6.04,1.96,-11.38,-4.82

Comment: This is in Croatia.

Comment: Thanks -- to clarify, are you saying I can't convert the Croatia datum to WGS 1984 unless the `+towgs84` information is included in its CRS?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200917/problem-with-mgi-crs-on-the-balkan and http://spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=MGI_/_Balkans_coordinate_systems

Comment: Yes. Datums based on Bessel will have  different coordinates than wgs84.

Comment: The +towgs numbers you gave work perfectly!  Can you tell me where you got them?  This website gives different numbers: http://spatial-analyst.net/CRS/gk_5.csy

Comment: The parameters are from http://epsg.io/3906-3964 which is more "official" than spatial-analyst.net. I have not tested the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mkennedy's comment above successfully solved this problem for me.

Here's what I did: I went to Settings -> Custom CRS and pasted

+x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=551.7,162.9,467.9,6.04,1.96,-11.38,-4.82 +units=m +no_defs

into the parameters box.

I then loaded the raster, chose the raster properties and set its CRS on the fly to the above custom datum, then set the Project CRS (lower right corner) to the same custom datum.  Then I added the shapefile layers, and they were perfectly aligned with the raster, and with each other -- I did not have to do anything further.  One shapefile was WGS 1984 and the other was MGI/Balkan zone 5.  So all this was achieved on the fly, all I needed was the proper +towgs numbers that mkennedy provided above.  Thanks all for your help!